# What's the chance of getting 5 enchantments on a diamond sword?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I got Sharpness 4, Unbreaking 3, Looting 3, Knockback 2, and Fire Aspect 2 on a diamond sword.
**What is the chance of this happening (not in any particular order)?**

In case it matters: I got these through a Sharpness 4 enchantment on the enchantment table.

Latest version as of posted date and max enchantment level of 30, ps4 if it matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need a couple of numbers:

- Enchantment level, the required experience level
- Enchantment power, the strength of the particular enchantment. For example, "Sharpness IV" has a power of 4.

##### Step 1

Minecraft applies two modifiers to the base enchantment level:

- The first modifier is based on the item's "enchantability," which depends on the material and the type of the item.
  Minecraft picks a number between 0 and half the enchantability, then adds that number plus one to the enchantment level. This random value follows a triangular distribution, this means that the medium value is more common than the extreme ones.

  ```
  rand_enchantability = 1 + randomInt(enchantability / 4 + 1) + randomInt(enchantability / 4 + 1);
  ```

  You used a diamond sword, so the base enchantability is 10.
  The first modifier then depends on the random traingular value in the interval [0,4], (so 1/9 to have 0, 2/9 to have 1, 3/9 to have 2, 2/9 to have 3, 1/9 to have 4).
  In this case we can assume that our random modifier will be:

  ```
  rand_enchant = 1 + 2 + 2 = 5
  ```
- The second modifier is the "modified enchantment level" and is calculated with this formula:

  ```
  mod_enchant_level = B + R1 + R2 + 1
  ```

  Where:

  - R1 and R2 are two individual randomly generated integers:

    - `R1 = randomInt(0, E / 4)`
    - `R2 = randomInt(0, E / 4)`
  - B is the base enchantment level
  - E is the enchantability of the item

    ```
    base_enchant_level = (randomInt(1,8) + floor(b / 2) + randomInt(0,b))
    ```

    where `b` is the number of bookshelves (maximum is 15)

    ```
    last_slot_level = floor(max(base, b × 2))
    ```

    Your enchantment was Sharpness IV, so we can assume to use the capped value `B = 30` (since Sharpness IV starts appearing between 26-30).

    Your item was a Diamond Sword, so `E = 10`

    ```
    mod_enchant_level = base_enchant_level + rand_enchant =  30 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 35
    ```

    Minecraft picks a value between 0.85 and 1.15, again with a triangular distribution. The modified enchantment level is multiplied by this value and then rounded. The best chance is to get 1, since it's a triangular distribution:

    ```
    mod_enchant_level = 35 * 1 = 35
    ```

##### Step 2

Minecraft makes a list of all enchantment types that can be applied to the target item along with the power that each enchantment has.

The power of each enchantment type is determined by the level and the values in the [enchantments levels table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting/Levels).

[image]

You got Sharpness 4, Unbreaking 3, Looting 3, Knockback 2, and Fire Aspect 2 so a modified level of 35 should be correct.

##### Step 3

Now that it has a list of the possible enchantments for the item, Minecraft must pick some of them to apply. Each enchantment has a statistical "weight". Enchantments with higher weights have a higher chance of being selected.

Minecraft uses the following weighted random selection algorithm:

- Calculate the total weight of all enchantments in the list (T).
- Pick a random integer from 0 to T – 1 as a number w, the weight.
- Iterate through each enchantment in the list, subtracting its weight from w. If w is now negative, select the current enchantment.

| Enchantment | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| Sharpness IV | 10 |
| Bane of Arthropods V | 5 |
| Knockback III | 5 |
| Smite V | 5 |
| Unbreakable III | 5 |
| Fire Aspect II | 2 |
| Looting III | 2 |

In our example `T = 34`, and the weight will be a random integer between (0,33). Hence, for each enchantment in the list, the probability of it being selected is: `P = w/T`

You didn't ask, but the chance to get those enchantments from this set was:

- Sharpness: 10/33 = 0.303 = 30.3%
- Knockback-Unbreakable: 5/23 = 0.217 = 21.7% and 5/18 = 0.278 = 27.8%
- Fire Aspect-Looting: 2/13 = 0.153 = 15.3% and 2/11 = 0.182 = 18.2%

The player always gets at least one enchantment on an item, and there is a chance of receiving more. Additional enchantments are chosen by this algorithm:

- With probability `(modified level + 1) / 50`, keep going. Otherwise, stop picking bonus enchantments.
- Remove from the list of possible enchantments anything that conflicts with previously-chosen enchantments.
- Pick one enchantment from the remaining possible enchantments based on the weights, and apply it to the item.
- Divide the modified level in half, rounded down, and repeat

Let's do some math.
You always get at least one enchantments. To get 5 enchantments you have to hit these 4 chances all together. Starting from a modified level of 35 and halving down we get:

```
p1 = (modified_level + 1) / 50 = 36 / 50 = 0.72
p2 = (modified_level/2 + 1) / 50 = 18 / 50 = 0.36
p3 = (modified_level/4 + 1) / 50 = 9 / 50 = 0.18
p4 = (modified_level/8 + 1) / 50 = 5 / 50 = 0.1
```

So the final chance to have 5 enchantments will be

```
p_final = 0.72 * 0.36 * 0.18 * 0.1 = 0.00467
```

which is, roughly, **0.467%**

More information on [Enchantment table](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting_mechanics#How_enchantments_are_chosen).

Comment: OK, lets go Mr. Math lol

Comment: @TimMcYeah if there's something wrong, it's friday night :')

Comment: Yeah agreed :')

Comment: Holy thanks for the indepth break down and final percentage

Comment: No worries, that was fun! :) some of the formulae used are from previous versions, I don't have the latest code available, but we can assume this wasn't changed drastically.